# JQuery Data Table example - Account Name not rendering

Tags: apex, visualforce

I am new to the `salesforce` and facing an issue where I don't know why `Account Name` details are not showing ?

**DataTableExampleController**

```
public class DataTableExampleController {
    public List<Contact> contactList{
        get{
            if(contactList == null){
                contactList = [SELECT Account.Name, FirstName, LastName, Phone FROM Contact limit 10000];
            }
            return contactList;
        }
        set;
    } 
}
```

**VFPage:**

```
<apex:page controller="DataTableExampleController" readOnly="true">
    <head>
        <apex:includeScript value="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js" />
        <apex:includescript value="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.4/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js" />
        <apex:stylesheet value="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.4/css/jquery.dataTables.css" />

        <script>
            j$ = jQuery.noConflict();
                j$(document).ready( function () {
                    var contactTable = j$('[id$="contacttable"]').DataTable({   
                });
            });
        </script>

        <body>
            <table id="contacttable" class="display">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Account</th>
                    <th>First Name</th>
                    <th>Last Name</th>
                    <th>Phone</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <apex:repeat value="{!contactList}" var="contact">
                    <tr>
                        <td>{!contact.Account.Name}</td>
                        <td>{!contact.FirstName}</td>
                        <td>{!contact.LastName}</td>
                        <td>{!contact.Phone}</td>
                    </tr>
                </apex:repeat>
            </tbody>
            </table>
        </body>
    </head>
</apex:page>
```

I dont see Account Name is not populating.

[image]

The below query shows the result too

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The empty fields for contacts with no account linked to them. Try to use this query in your controller:

```
[SELECT Account.Name, FirstName, LastName, Phone FROM Contact WHERE Account.Name <> null limit 10000];
```

Or just click on the Account header in your table to sort by the name.